# How do I sign a new FreeIPA Server's internal CA with my organizational internal CA?

Tags: openssl, certificate-authority, freeipa, certutil

My organization has an internal Certificate Authority (CA) which we have already generated many internal certificates and have installed on machines.

I am setting up a [FreeIPA LDAP/Kerberos server](https://www.freeipa.org/) and after the initial install, it has generated an internal CA of it's own which I can see in the web interface.

I'd like to sign the FreeIPA CA with the existing organization's CA to establish a certificate trust chain. I am following [the FreeIPA instructions for Renewing an Externally-Signed IdM CA Certificate Manually](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/linux_domain_identity_authentication_and_policy_guide/cert-renewal#manual-cert-renewal-ext) which I believe cover signing the FreeIPA CA with an external CA. This produced a CSR which I signed using the existing CA to produce a new signed FreeIPA CA.

However, I got stuck trying to re-import the newly signed CA + Certificate Chain using the `ipa-cacert-manage renew --external-cert-file` command. When I run that as the instructions say to, I get an error that the CA certificate chain is incomplete because it's missing one of the certificates in the chain:

```
[root@lockandkey ~]# ipa-cacert-manage renew --external-cert-file=/tmp/LockAndKey_FreeIPA_CA.crt  --external-cert-file=/tmp/dfca.crt --external-cert-file=/tmp/jgca.crt 
Importing the renewed CA certificate, please wait
CA certificate chain in /tmp/LockAndKey_FreeIPA_CA.crt, 
/tmp/dfca.crt, /tmp/jgca.crt is incomplete: missing certificate with subject 
'E=domains@digitalfruition.com,CN=ca.digitalfruition.com,OU=Internal CA,O=Digital Fruition\, LLC,L=Newland,ST=North Carolina,C=US'
The ipa-cacert-manage command failed.
```

However, that certificate *was* provided in one of the `--external-cert-file` arguments. I also tried with a "CA Bundle" file (multiple certificates in one file) and the result was the same.

Digging in further, the issue actually appears to be from [`load_external_cert` in installutils.py](https://github.com/freeipa/freeipa/blob/master/ipaserver/install/installutils.py#L1041)

```
    trust_chain = list(reversed(nssdb.get_trust_chain(ca_nickname)))
    ca_cert_chain = []
    for nickname in trust_chain:
        cert, subject, issuer = cache[nickname]
        ca_cert_chain.append(cert)
        if subject == issuer:
            break
    else:
        raise ScriptError(
            "CA certificate chain in %s is incomplete: "
            "missing certificate with subject '%s'" %
            (", ".join(files), issuer))
```

Running `ipa-cacert-manage renew` in verbose mode shows that *it does find all certificates in the chain* but when it gets to the [art where `trust_chain` is formed, the `trust_chain` *only contains the FreeIPA certificate and not the rest of teh chain*. I was able to reproduce the scenario by unwinding the commands and replaying them in my terminal. Here's where it breaks down:

FreeIPA's `ipa-cacert-manage renew` is calling on `certutil` to "Print the certificate chain" using the `-O` option, as follows:

```
[root@lockandkey ~]# /usr/bin/certutil -d dbm:/tmp/tmppTphXX -O -n 'CN=Certificate Authority,O=FARCRY.SITEPALETTE.COM' -f /tmp/tmppTphXX/pwdfile.txt
"CN=Certificate Authority,O=FARCRY.SITEPALETTE.COM" [CN=Certificate Authority,O=FARCRY.SITEPALETTE.COM]
```

However `certutil` is not printing the entire chain, even though the certificate is signed by another CA which is in the truststore. You can see that `certutil` does show the *proper* chain when I call it on the intermediate CA:

```
[root@lockandkey ~]# /usr/bin/certutil -d dbm:/tmp/tmppTphXX -O -n 'E=domains@digitalfruition.com,CN=ca.digitalfruition.com,OU=Internal CA,O=Digital Fruition\, LLC,L=Newland,ST=North Carolina,C=US' -f /tmp/tmppTphXX/pwdfile.txt
"E=CA@josh.gitlin.name,CN=Joshua Gitlin,OU=ca.josh.gitlin.name,O=Personal Certificate Authority,L=Newland,ST=North Carolina,C=US" [E=CA@josh.gitlin.name,CN=Joshua Gitlin,OU=ca.josh.gitlin.name,O=Personal Certificate Authority,L=Newland,ST=North Carolina,C=US]

  "E=domains@digitalfruition.com,CN=ca.digitalfruition.com,OU=Internal CA,O=Digital Fruition\, LLC,L=Newland,ST=North Carolina,C=US" [E=domains@digitalfruition.com,CN=ca.digitalfruition.com,OU=Internal CA,O="Digital Fruition, LLC",L=Newland,ST=North Carolina,C=US]
```

So I believe this is an issue with `certutil`, but this is as far as I've gotten so far.

Debugging this further I have decided that for some reason `certutil` doesn't like the certificate I generated, so it may be an issue with something on that CSR. Other certificates validate fine...

Am I doing something wrong? What's the proper way to sign a FreeIPA Certificate Authority with another internal CA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. The CSR generated by FreeIPA includes the "X509v3 Authority Key Identifier" extension set to the key ID of the FreeIPA private key. This causes `certutil` to believe the CA is self-signed and does not follow the certificate chain.

When signing a CSR from FreeIPA, *do not* copy the X509v3 Authority Key Identifier extension. Then the validation will be successful.

(Also: make sure the signed CA certificate used UTF8 for encoding the subject name; see [Subject name encoding mismatch](https://www.freeipa.org/page/Troubleshooting/PKI#External_CA_renewal_with_ipa-cacert-manage_fails) in the documentation)